# How to start a ROS node on startup?

Tags: ros, startup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using an Odroid U3 with my robot, Ubuntu 14.04. I am using an external computer to launch the ROS node of the robot.

I was wondering if there is a way to start ROS in the robot after the Odroid starts up. Like if the robot were turned on with the ROS node running after the startup. That way I would not have to use the external computer. Right now I do not need to monitor the robot so it is OK if I do not have a roscore running externally.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193181/how-to-start-a-ros-node-on-startup?/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked many times before, a simple search gives me the following answers:

- [autostart a launchfile after/while boot](http://answers.ros.org/question/52044/autostart-a-launchfile-afterwhile-boot/)
- [Best practices for launching ROS on startup](http://answers.ros.org/question/10904/best-practices-for-launching-ros-on-startup/)

Answers to both questions point the OPs to [clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart) and [ros-system-daemon-groovy](https://github.com/TurtleBot-Mfg/ros-system-daemon-groovy), which seem like good starting points to get something working.

Major advantage of the 'upstart' approach is that it automatically takes care of waiting for your network (and any other required services) to come up before starting `roscore` fi. Unless you have very specific reasons (ie: no upstart support), I'd refrain from writing something yourself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2019-01-25**:
I've started using systemctl instead of upstart. Seems like that's the way the linux community is going. In order to do this I add the file my-service.service to /etc/systemd/system that runs a bash file I've stored under /usr/sbin/my-service. It can be enable and disable using systemctl commands

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Google how to execute shell-script-files (not batch) in linux at startup, write yourself a script that calls your `roslaunch <my_package> <my_launchfile>` and presto, you'll have the node running whenever linux boots :)

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-22**:
Batch is for Windows. On Linux we use the Shell (Or the Bash).